# In Flutter, is there a way to put a widget on top of a WebView to block some part of the WebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter, I tried several WebView plugins and tried to use "Stack", "Positioned" so that I could put a block(Like a Card or anything) on top of a WebView and failed to succeed. WebView is always on the top before other widgets.

I guess there is no way to do so by using Flutter. Am I right?

Tried flutter_webview_plugin

Comment: flutter webview plugin isn't part of flutter view tree. so once its open you can't draw anything on top of it. try webview_flutter But that isn't reliable since it has many issues reading input tags.

Answer (score 0):

flutter_webview_plugin doesn't support this, as is documented in its [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin). But [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) should support it.